# Clean phone numbers which has special characters and alphabets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have junk in the phone number field, and I want to clean them. I would like to know how to query to check if there are any special or alphabetic characters in the phone number field. Can anyone help please?
I tried this query and didn't work. I need the code in PostgreSQL

```
select phone from table where phone like '[^[:alpha:]]' and phone <>''
-- and phone not like '[^0-9]'
order by phone
```

input value in the table looks like:

```
Phone
-----
(443)-554-6677
111-111-1111
345-rty-34fr
4345434444 ext
```

Output(should look like this valid phone numbers)

```
(443)-554-6677
111-111-1111
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thank You,
Swathi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to get the required output:

```
select phone from t1 where phone<>'' and phone!~'[[:alpha:]]';
```

[image: output]

You seem to be trying to use regular expression syntax with the `like` operator, but this is not correct. The [`like` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is extremely limited; it basically only offers the `%` prefix/suffix wildcard, and the `_` single-character wildcard.

---

If you want to be even stricter, we can do something like this:

```
select phone from t1 where phone~'^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$';
```

[image: output]

---

**Test fixture**

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (phone text);
insert into t1 (phone) values ('(443)-554-6677'), ('111-111-1111'), ('345-rty-34fr'), ('4345434444 ext');
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank You so much for the explanation and answering my question. It worked for me.

Comment: Hi ,
If i want to filter the bad phone numbers which has junk like all the 10digits have the same number how to i filter them .For instance patterns of numbers: like 111111 
patterns of numbers: like 000000
patterns of numbers: like 999999


Phone
-------
333-333-3333
5555555555
(666)666-666
00011111111
I would like to get the count of this kind of formate

Answer (score 0):

I have used this script to format US phone numbers into international format. It works really well. This script looks to see if the number is intentionally formatted and if yes, removes all useless characters I have found that if a number is ever stored with +######### formatting then it is a good number 99 percent of the time. And if it is stored with (###)###-#### formatting then it is a US Canada UK number 99 percent of the time. And that 99 percent of statistics are made up on the spot.

One downside is that this script does nothing to slice out extensions, you can do that by checking to see if the pclean output starts with +1 and is greater than 12 characters long. If yes then slice(12,-1) or something like that.

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phone) {
    input = phone
    if (input==null){input = "3456"}
    pclean = input.replace(/[^0-9\+]/g, "") //works
    clean = pclean.replace(/^0*/g, "")
    clean = clean.replace(/^1*/g, "")
    if (pclean.charAt(0) != "+" ) {pclean = "+1" + clean    }

    if(pclean.length < 12){pclean = null}
    return pclean 
}
```